# Do I need both the account number and also the sort code to make a deposit into friend account or can I just use the account number?

Tags: united-kingdom, banking

Is it possible to make a payment into someone's account using only their account number and name or do I need to give a sort code as well??

Answer (score 4):

You will need sort code as well if you are making electronic transfer.

If you are visiting the beneficiary bank, it may be possible to deposit with just account number and name, as the cashier can look up the same.

Comment: I've never tried either of the following, but... This may work if you visited the _branch_ where the recipient had their account (saying something like "_I know her account is at this branch_"). If it was just a random branch of the recipient's bank, I _suspect_ you would still need the sort-code, either because looking up the sort-code may be considered revealing personal information, and/or because counter staff may not (easily) be able to do such a search (e.g. they might only be able to search by, e.g. account number, and have to manually check the name from a lengthy list).